# MVC 3 routing issue http://bleh.com/globalString/Controller/action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am not sure if this is even possible. What I would like to do is have a URL like:

```
http://bleh.com/globalString/Controller/action
```

Where "globalString" would need to be pulled out to be parsed and setup some variables.  This string is basically the client name.

Then we would have controller and actions as normal after that.

as a slightly additional question when the default routing is setup when creating a new MVC app do I need to delete the mapping it creates or put my new mapping before or after it?

Thanks, (as you might be able to tell this is still my first exploration into MVC)

Comment: How will this `globalString` be calculated? You mention something about a client name but on what does this client name depend?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you need to put this rule **before** default mapping route. The route engine searched route maps based on the adding order. So you need to put the more specific rules ahead.

But because your /globalString/Controller/action is conflict with default route /Controller/action/id, there's no way for route engine to enter the /Controller/action/id route. So you must add some constraint to the former. Such as regex patterns etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the method `public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)` in `System.Web.Routing.Route`. There you can do almost everything concerning the route.